# android studio build failed - DebugManifest

Tags: javascript, java, android

can anyone help me with that ?
i don't know how to fix it

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHkjq.png

- Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$MultipleTaskActionFailures: Multiple task action failures occurred:
- Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
- Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
- Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbu found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-18.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:18.0.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-20.1.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:20.1.2)
- Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$MultipleTaskActionFailures: Multiple task action failures occurred:
- Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The minCompileSdk (32) specified in a
- Android resource compilation failed
  C:\Users\GEV\Desktop\StrangerRepo\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-w٣٢٠dp-land-v13\values-w٣٢٠dp-land-v13.xml: AAPT: error: invalid configuration 'w٣٢٠dp-land-v13'.

Answer (score 0):

Set both compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 31 in your build.gradle(app) file.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31 // <-- This
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        targetSdkVersion 31 // <-- and this too
        // ...
    }
}
```